# Input overlay on embedded video

Tags: javascript, flash, video

I've been taking the [AI class](http://www.ai-class.com) from Stanford that Peter Norvig and Sebastian Thrun are teaching.

Each class is split into a few dozen different 30 sec to 4 min video lectures and at the end of most of them the screen is paused and there is a user input overlay of the video with checkboxes, radio buttons or text fields along with a 'Done' button.  The inputs are placed in such a way that they are in relevant places on the underlying video.  For example, one of the first videos went over search strategies over graphs, the graphs were drawn and then check boxes were overlayed near the nodes the question was over.

Does anyone have any idea how this is implemented?

Comment: Do you know the video format & the player? If the video is played in web browser (using Flash or HTML5), it's possible to be overlaid by form widgets

Comment: Yes.  It is Flash in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Details to follow when I get time but it looks like it is done with a clever trick:

At the end of the video, the video is overlayed with an image of the last frame which is, in turn, overlayed with the form widgets.

I will elaborate as soon as I get the time to put something together.